# What's the fastest way to transfer files from PC to Android?

Tags: wi-fi, adb, file-transfer, files

I'd like to know which method of transfering offers the highest speeds. It happens once in a while that I lose my data while making ROM updates etc. as my phone is encrypted and that sometimes makes issues.

I'm using a OnePlus One with its fast charging cable. I wonder if I'm faster transfering files using adb push instead of using Windows Explorer. I reckon that I read that somewhere. Or are there WiFi apps that can transfer quicker?

Thanks!

Comment: The quickest would be a USB 3 connection (if the phone has the capability to transfer data in USB 3 mode). Then `adb pull/push` are also the fastest (MTP is slow due to abstraction). WiFi is slower than a wired connection due to interference and the added overhead because of packet headers. Depending on what type of data you send, a wireless SFTP connection with compression enabled might be the fastest (requires compressible data, though).

Comment: @GiantTree What you posted is exactly what I personally was looking for as an answer. If you make that an answer, I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is

**It depends on the situation.**

Let me explain: Some solution make work better than others for some files than others. For instance, use Bluetooth to send a picture, or Wi-Fi based FTP for small files. For larger files, you may want to use a cable and transfer them manually, or even load these files onto a high-speed SD card and plug that into your PC. It really depends on circumstance. For me, I send files by Wi-Fi to my laptop for anything smaller than 100mb, then cable it for bigger files.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually made an app specifically so I can transfer files to and from my phone at the absolute fastest speeds possible. Here's the link for the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.brandonharris.speedsyncads and here's a YouTube video explaining how to use it https://youtu.be/Qbjg7Hh-pCc

Comment: Any comparative stats from your performance testing?

Comment: On my Nexus 6P the fastest speeds I get are 300 Mbps to the PC and 500 Mbps from the PC.

Comment: So, that is great. But to be "the absolute fastest" means that there is a lower "fastest" you are beating. What comparison values were you using, and what is their source?

Comment: Most devices have USB 2.0 ports. The max theoretical bandwidth of the USB 2.0 port is 480 Mbps. However, with the newer versions of Android in order to actually transfer files you have to manually select that you want to transfer files each time. So in the real world a wireless transfer would be faster, not to mention easier. But, mobile devices just aren't powerful enough to max out the wireless hardware using the most common wireless protocols, i.e. SMB, FTP, WebDAV, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I am using an APP Web PC Suite to wireless transfer files between mobile and PC.  It's very easy and fast to share files when your phone and pc are in the same Wi-Fi network. Most importantly, it's totally free.

Comment: Please link app from play store